# Error: "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So I am making this ChatBot trained on a month of reddit comments. The Script i'm currently working on creates a DB and loads it with some data from a JSON file.

When I run the code, it does in fact manage to create the sqlite3 DB, but it prints out an error:

`Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
 Extra data: line 1 column 16 (char 15)
 Extra data: line 1 column 8 (char 7)
 Extra data: line 1 column 11 (char 10)
 Extra data: line 1 column 8 (char 7)
 Extra data: line 1 column 9 (char 8)
 Extra data: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
 Extra data: line 1 column 9 (char 8)
 Extra data: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
 Extra data: line 1 column 17 (char 16)
 Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)
 Extra data: line 1 column 12 (char 11)
 Extra data: line 1 column 13 (char 12)
 Extra data: line 1 column 13 (char 12)
 Extra data: line 1 column 26 (char 25)
 Extra data: line 1 column 21 (char 20)
 Extra data: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
 Extra data: line 1 column 16 (char 15)
 Extra data: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
 Extra data: line 1 column 20 (char 19)
 Extra data: line 1 column 16 (char 15)
 Extra data: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
 Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Anyone that can tell me what I can do to fix this?

BTW heres the entire code:

```
import sqlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time
import ast

timeframe = '2015-01'
sql_transaction = []
start_row = 0
cleanup = 1000000

connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format(timeframe))
c = connection.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT)")


def format_data(data):
    data = data.replace('\n', ' newlinechar ').replace('\r', ' newlinechar ').replace('"', "'")
    return data


def transaction_bldr(sql):
    global sql_transaction
    sql_transaction.append(sql)
    if len(sql_transaction) > 1000:
        c.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
        for s in sql_transaction:
            try:
                c.execute(s)
            except:
                pass
        connection.commit()
        sql_transaction = []


def sql_insert_replace_comment(commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit, time, score):
    try:
        sql = """UPDATE parent_reply SET parent_id = ?, comment_id = ?, parent = ?, comment = ?, subreddit = ?, unix = ?, score = ? WHERE parent_id =?;""".format(
            parentid, commentid, parent, comment, subreddit, int(time), score, parentid)
        transaction_bldr(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print('s0 insertion', str(e))


def sql_insert_has_parent(commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit, time, score):
    try:
        sql = """INSERT INTO parent_reply (parent_id, comment_id, parent, comment, subreddit, unix, score) VALUES ("{}","{}","{}","{}","{}",{},{});""".format(
            parentid, commentid, parent, comment, subreddit, int(time), score)
        transaction_bldr(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print('s0 insertion', str(e))


def sql_insert_no_parent(commentid, parentid, comment, subreddit, time, score):
    try:
        sql = """INSERT INTO parent_reply (parent_id, comment_id, comment, subreddit, unix, score) VALUES ("{}","{}","{}","{}",{},{});""".format(
            parentid, commentid, comment, subreddit, int(time), score)
        transaction_bldr(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print('s0 insertion', str(e))


def acceptable(data):
    if len(data.split(' ')) > 1000 or len(data) < 1:
        return False
    elif len(data) > 32000:
        return False
    elif data == '[deleted]':
        return False
    elif data == '[removed]':
        return False
    else:
        return True


def find_parent(pid):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT comment FROM parent_reply WHERE comment_id = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execute(sql)
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result != None:
            return result[0]
        else:
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        # print(str(e))
        return False


def find_existing_score(pid):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT score FROM parent_reply WHERE parent_id = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execute(sql)
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result != None:
            return result[0]
        else:
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        # print(str(e))
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open(r'C:\Users\hermans\Desktop\RedditBot\RC_2015-01.json', buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            # print(row)
            # time.sleep(555)
            row_counter += 1

            if row_counter > start_row:
                try:
                    row = json.loads(row)
                    parent_id = row['parent_id'].split('_')[1]
                    body = format_data(row['body'])
                    created_utc = row['created_utc']
                    score = row['score']

                    comment_id = row['id']

                    subreddit = row['subreddit']
                    parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)

                    existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
                    if existing_comment_score:
                        if score > existing_comment_score:
                            if acceptable(body):
                                sql_insert_replace_comment(comment_id, parent_id, parent_data, body, subreddit, created_utc, score)

                    else:
                        if acceptable(body):
                            if parent_data:
                                if score >= 2:
                                    sql_insert_has_parent(comment_id, parent_id, parent_data, body, subreddit, created_utc, score)
                                    paired_rows += 1
                            else:
                                sql_insert_no_parent(comment_id, parent_id, body, subreddit, created_utc, score)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))

            if row_counter % 100000 == 0:
                print('Total Rows Read: {}, Paired Rows: {}, Time: {}'.format(row_counter, paired_rows, str(datetime.now())))

            #if row_counter > start_row:
            #    if row_counter % cleanup == 0:
            #        print("Cleanin up!")
            #        sql = "DELETE FROM parent_reply WHERE parent IS NULL"
            #        c.execute(sql)
            #        connection.commit()
            #        c.execute("VACUUM")
            #        connection.commit()
```

And the JSON file (It contains way more comments than this, but dont wanna paste in 200.000 lines...):

```
{
    "score_hidden": false,
    "name": "t1_cnas8zv",
    "link_id": "t3_2qyr1a",
    "body": "Most of us have some family members like this. *Most* of my family is like this. ",
    "downs": 0,
    "created_utc": "1420070400",
    "score": 14,
    "author": "YoungModern",
    "distinguished": null,
    "id": "cnas8zv",
    "archived": false,
    "parent_id": "t3_2qyr1a",
    "subreddit": "exmormon",
    "author_flair_css_class": null,
    "author_flair_text": null,
    "gilded": 0,
    "retrieved_on": 1425124282,
    "ups": 14,
    "controversiality": 0,
    "subreddit_id": "t5_2r0gj",
    "edited": false
} {
    "distinguished": null,
    "id": "cnas8zw",
    "archived": false,
    "author": "RedCoatsForever",
    "score": 3,
    "created_utc": "1420070400",
    "downs": 0,
    "body": "But Mill's career was way better. Bentham is like, the Joseph Smith to Mill's Brigham Young.",
    "link_id": "t3_2qv6c6",
    "name": "t1_cnas8zw",
    "score_hidden": false,
    "controversiality": 0,
    "subreddit_id": "t5_2s4gt",
    "edited": false,
    "retrieved_on": 1425124282,
    "ups": 3,
    "author_flair_css_class": "on",
    "gilded": 0,
    "author_flair_text": "Ontario",
    "subreddit": "CanadaPolitics",
    "parent_id": "t1_cnas2b6"
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have now tried  to romove the try: Except:, but now I encounter a new Error I do not understand, and actually encountered earlier:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\hermans\Desktop\RedditBot\Current_Create_DB.py", line 121, in <module>
    row = json.loads(row)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

Comment: what you show is not a valid json file. check for youself https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And the JSON file (It contains way more comments than this, but dont wanna paste in 200.000 lines...):

What you have shown is not valid JSON. Snipping out a bunch of data lines, we see the general problem:

```
{
    "score_hidden": false,
} {
    "distinguished": null,
}
```

The `} {` is because your data contains multiple JSON objects (as the JSON standard calls them) one after another - rather than having them nested within another layer (presumably a JSON array, again in the standard's terminology). It should instead look something like:

```
[
    {
        "score_hidden": false,
    }, {
        "distinguished": null,
    }
]
```

The error you're getting is giving you details about the JSON parser's failure to interpret the invalid JSON (because it is invalid). This becomes clear when you read the error message properly - by looking at the exception traceback. However, your code as written is preventing you from doing this, by printing only the exception message and then proceeding as if nothing bad had happened:

```
try:
    row = json.loads(row)
    # lots more code not relevant to the reported error                    
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

**Do not do this**. You are only making things harder for yourself. The way to fix problems with your code is to **write less code at a time**, and then **make sure it works** before proceeding. This kind of exception handling is the opposite, and leads to posting lots of code on SO that's irrelevant to the problem because you've lost the relevant guidance :)

If you had left out this try/except block, your code would bail out immediately on the first error, but it would show you something more useful. It would point to the `row = json.loads(row)` line, and it would label the error as a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`, which is a big hint. But more importantly, code that keeps running after something goes wrong, without a real attempt to fix the problem (or at least *properly* determine that it can safely be ignored), has a chance to mess up your data further. In the long run this will cause you much pain and misery, so this is my attempt to shake you out of the habit now :)

Comment: Actually, now that I read the code more closely... another big problem here is that you're trying to read a JSON file a line at a time. JSON is **not intended for this**. You can't just `json.load` a single line of the file, because a single line of a JSON file is not in itself valid JSON except by coincidence. This causes the same sorts of errors, but for a different reason, and even after ensuring that the JSON is valid.